# convergence of the series $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{\lfloor\sqrt{n+1}\rfloor}-\left(-1\right)^{\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor}}{n} $

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{\lfloor\sqrt{n+1}\rfloor}-\left(-1\right)^{\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor}}{n} $

Im having trouble trying to determine if this series converge absolutely or conditionally. Any ideas will help. I noticed that when $ \sqrt{n+1} \in Z $ then $ \left(-1\right)^{\lfloor\sqrt{n+1}\rfloor}-\left(-1\right)^{\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor} =-2 $  or $ \left(-1\right)^{\lfloor\sqrt{n+1}\rfloor}-\left(-1\right)^{\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor}=2 $

But i cant tell more then that.

Comment: I think you can tell more than that since by what you already wrote it is clear the series cannot converge absolutely...

Comment: @DonAntonio:  yes, it can, because most of the terms are zero.  The surviving ones decrease fast enough so the sum converges absolutely.

Comment: @RossMillikan I'm referring to what the OP wrote: that the numerator is either $\;2\;$ or $\;-2\;$ ...

Comment: @DonAntonio:  only when $n+1$ is a perfect square, which OP represented as $\sqrt {n+1} \in \Bbb Z$, implying it is zero other times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to turn what you noticed, which is important, into the fact that the only surviving terms have $n+1=k^2$, so they have $k^2-1$ in the denominator.  Now you can use the fact that the sum of inverse squares converges.

Comment: Im having trouble writing formal proof. I want to write this: $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{|\left(-1\right)^{\lfloor\sqrt{n+1}\rfloor}-\left(-1\right)^{\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor}|}{n}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{|\left(-1\right)^{\lfloor\sqrt{n+1}\rfloor}-\left(-1\right)^{\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor}|}{k^{2}-1}\leq\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2}{k^{2}} $ but im not sure how to do it correct. because in the last sum we dont have dependence on n in the term so it looks wrong. (k is the number such $ k^2=\sqrt{n+1} $

Comment: I would change the sum variable to $k$.  To do that you have to argue that all the terms you lose because they do not correspond to a whole number $k$ are zero.  You also want to start with $k=2$ to avoid the division by $0$ which is OK because you did not have $n=0$ which would cause $k=1$.